# Filter stream using correlation between stream elements

Tags: java, java-stream, reduction

Let’s say there’s a `Person` class that looks like this:

```
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String discriminator;
    // some other fields plus getters/setters
}
```

Now I have a `Stream` of `Person` elements and that stream may contain multiple `Person` instances that have same `id`, but different `discriminator` values, i.e. `[Person{“id”: 1, “discriminator”: “A”}, Person{“id”: 1, “discriminator”: “B”}, Person{“id”: 2, “discriminator”: “A”}, ...]`

What I’d like to do is to filter out all `Person` instances  with some id if there’s at least one `Person` instance with that id that has a particular discriminator value. So, continuing with the above example, filtering by discriminator value “A” would yield an empty collection (after the reduction operation, of course) and filtering by discriminator value “B” would yield a collection not containing any `Person` instance with id equal to 1.

I know I can reduce the stream using `groupingBy` collector and group elements by `Person.id` and then remove the mapping from the resulting `Map` if the mapped list contains a `Person` element with the specified discriminator value, but am still wondering if there’s a simpler way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your problem correctly, you would first find all `ID`s that would match a discriminator:

```
Set<Integer> ids = persons.stream()
       .filter(p -> "A".equalsIgnoreCase(p.getDiscriminator()))
       .map(Person::getId)
       .collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

And then remove the entries that would match those:

```
persons.removeIf(x -> ids.contains(x.getId()))
```

Comment: Probably `Collectors.toSet()` will be better?

Comment: @123-xyz don't think so, the OP has not shown any hashcode/equals; I did not want to assume

Comment: Yep, your solution presents exactly what I’d like to achieve, but I’d like to do it without creating any intermediate data structure like ids collection in your example... if that’s even possible.

Comment: @jigga I doubt it, thing is you need to traverse it once without actually affecting it to get the correct `Id`s; I was thinking of some in-place removal at first, but that would destroy the integrity of the problem

Comment: @Eugene: replacing the `List<Integer>` by `Set<Integer>` doesn’t require any effort on the OP’s side, `Integer` does already have a suitable `hashCode()` implementation. Since you are invoking `ids.contains(…)` for each person, that would clearly improve the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Eugenes answer works great, but I personally prefer a single statement. So I took his code and put it all together into a single operation. Which looks like this:

```
final List<Person> result = persons.stream()
    .filter(p -> "B".equalsIgnoreCase(p.getDiscriminator()))
    .map(Person::getId)
    .collect(
        () -> new ArrayList<>(persons),
        ( list, id ) -> list.removeIf(p -> p.getId() == id),
        ( a, b ) -> {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
    );
```

Probably need to mention that the copy of `persons` is needed, else the Stream will corrupt and encounters `null` values.

> **SideNote**: This version is currently throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException` when trying to use in parallel.

Comment: I don’t see the advantage of “a single statement” that is much bigger than the two statements of the other answer together, not to speak of the inefficiency of performing a `removeIf` that will traverse the entire list potentially *for each element* (also known as quadratic time complexity).

Answer (score 1):

So below I present the solution that I've come up with. First I group the input Person collection/stream by the Person.id attribute and then I stream over the map entries and filter out those that have at least one value that matches given discriminator.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(
            new Person(1, "A"),
            new Person(1, "B"),
            new Person(1, "C"),
            new Person(2, "B"),
            new Person(2, "C"),
            new Person(3, "A"),
            new Person(3, "C"),
            new Person(4, "B")
        );

        System.out.println(persons);
        System.out.println(filterByDiscriminator(persons, "A"));
        System.out.println(filterByDiscriminator(persons, "B"));
        System.out.println(filterByDiscriminator(persons, "C"));
    }

    private static List<Person> filterByDiscriminator(List<Person> input, String discriminator) {
        return input.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getId))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().stream().noneMatch(person -> person.getDiscriminator().equals(discriminator)))
            .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}

class Person {

    private final Integer id;
    private final String discriminator;

    public Person(Integer id, String discriminator) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(id);
        Objects.requireNonNull(discriminator);
        this.id = id;
        this.discriminator = discriminator;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getDiscriminator() {
        return discriminator;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s{\"id\": %d, \"discriminator\": \"%s\"}", getClass().getSimpleName(), id, discriminator);
    }
}
```

Comment: Plus one for creativity. Note that when you are not processing the keys, you can use `values()` instead of `entrySet()` which eliminates the need to call `entry.getValue()` all the time: `… values().stream()  .filter(list -> list.stream().noneMatch(person -> person.getDiscriminator() .equals(discriminator)))  .flatMap(List::stream) .collect(Collectors.toList());`